# Problem with unresolved external symbol of a variable in a class with _beginthread

Tags: c++, class, static, beginthreadex

I'm not sure why a `static` declared variable is not being recognized in my C++ class. I am using `_beginthreadex()`, so from what I found, it seems I need the class function containing `_beginthreadex()` to be declared as `static`.

Here is a working example, compiled with Visual Studio 2019.

The main program `main.cpp` simply initializes the class:

```
#include "CWinSock.h"
CWinSock *clsCWinSock;
INT main(INT argc, char* argv[])
{
    clsCWinSock = new CWinSock();
    while (1)
        ;    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the simple class header `CWinSock.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
class CWinSock
{
    public:
        CWinSock();
        ~CWinSock();
        void CreateServer();
        static UINT dwServerPort;
    private:
        static unsigned WINAPI ListenAndAccept(void*);
};
```

And here is the class .cpp file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>    /* _beginthread, _endthread */
#include "CWinSock.h"

UINT CWinSock::dwServerPort;
CWinSock::CWinSock() {dwServerPort = 61801;}
CWinSock::~CWinSock() {}

static unsigned WINAPI ListenAndAccept(void *)
{
    UINT dwPort = CWinSock::dwServerPort;
    return 0;
}

void CWinSock::CreateServer()
{
    // Call the main example routine.
    UINT threadID = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &ListenAndAccept, NULL, 0, &threadID);    
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

This is the basics, yet I get the error: `LNK2001, unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int CWinSock::dwServerPort" (?dwServerPort@CWinSock@@2IA)`. Putting `UINT CWinSock::dwServerPort;` in the .cpp file solves that error.

BUT, it ALSO errors on the function `ListenAndAccept`. Even if I declare it in the .cpp file as suggested, it still gives an error.

It doesn't give the error if I take off the `static`, but from what I understand (which might be incorrect), `_beginthreadex()` won't work without its function being `static`? Or I'm doing something really wrong?

Any help in calling `_beginthreadex()` from a class and the ***reason*** for `static` is appreciated also!

Comment: You must also ***define*** the static class member in one of the cpp file. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: I did `static UINT dwServerPort;` and `UINT dwServerPort;` in the .cpp file, but it still gives the same error. I put in `UINT CWinSock::dwServerPort;` and that worked.